# How to latest data in array of objects database mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to sort data in an array of objects. The problem is I don't have any date property so I can't be able to show the latest data,

I am trying to sort it like out this way but it is not working.

```
 const filter2 = data.sort((a, b) => (a > b ? -1 : 1))
```

Here is my data example

```
const data = [
        {
            _id: "6221943a03931299eb8c343b",
            title: "product 1",
            brand: "Beats",
            reg_price: "299",
            sale_price: "200",
            stock: "150",
        },
        {
            _id: "6221943a03931299eb8c343b",
            title: "product 2",
            brand: "Beats",
            reg_price: "299",
            sale_price: "200",
            stock: "150",
        },
        {
            _id: "6221943a03931299eb8c343b",
            title: "product 3",
            brand: "Beats",
            reg_price: "299",
            sale_price: "200",
            stock: "150",
        },
        {
            _id: "6221943a03931299eb8c343b",
            title: "product 4",
            brand: "Beats",
            reg_price: "299",
            sale_price: "200",
            stock: "150",
        },
        {
            _id: "6221943a03931299eb8c343b",
            title: "product 4",
            brand: "Beats",
            reg_price: "299",
            sale_price: "200",
            stock: "150",
        },
    ]
```

Comment: I think you said your issue - `The problem is I don't have any date property so I can't be able to show the latest data`. add a date property if you want to sort by latest

Comment: I can't add a date property because I have more data on my database, so I want to do it without date property

Comment: you have to sort on some property...if you want latest, you need to compare a date.

Comment: You can't just compare whole object to object when sorting. You need to sort on a field. Mostly it's date but you don't have date. Logically think about it, when you sort dinnerware at home, you sort by size (big plates, small plates etc.). You need some kind of differentiator in order to sort, currently you have none

Comment: sort with respect to what property do you need to make some general function that sort according to the object property ?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this if you want to sort it concerning object property

```
const data = [
        {
            _id: "6221943a03931299eb8c343b",
            title: "product 1",
            brand: "Beats",
            reg_price: "299",
            sale_price: "200",
            stock: "150",
        },
        {
            _id: "6221943a03931299eb8c343b",
            title: "product 2",
            brand: "Beats",
            reg_price: "299",
            sale_price: "200",
            stock: "150",
        },
        {
            _id: "6221943a03931299eb8c343b",
            title: "product 3",
            brand: "Beats",
            reg_price: "299",
            sale_price: "200",
            stock: "150",
        },
        {
            _id: "6221943a03931299eb8c343b",
            title: "product 4",
            brand: "Beats",
            reg_price: "299",
            sale_price: "200",
            stock: "150",
        },
        {
            _id: "6221943a03931299eb8c343b",
            title: "product 4",
            brand: "Beats",
            reg_price: "299",
            sale_price: "200",
            stock: "150",
        },
    ]

// sortProperty = '_id' | 'title' | 'brand' | 'reg_price' | 'sale_price' | 'stock'
const sortFunc = (sortArr,sortProperty) => sortArr.sort((a,b) => a[sortProperty] - b[sortProperty])

console.log(sortFunc(data,'_id'))
```